# LIKE query with AES_DECRYPT not working

Tags: mysql, sql, aes

I have a table containing several ENCRYPTED `blob` fields. The data was encrypted with `AES_ENCRYPT`. I am now trying to generate ajax suggestions from these fields.

The following query does not work

```
    SELECT id
           , AES_DECRYPT(first_field,'secret_salt')
           , AES_DECRYPT(second_field,'secret_salt')
    FROM   table
    WHERE  ( AES_DECRYPT(first_field,'secret_salt')  "%user search value%" 
       OR    AES_DECRYPT(second_field,'secret_salt') LIKE "%user search value%"
           ) 
      AND  status = 1
```

I have been searching and trying for the last 3 days. The following query does work, but is not according to my needs

```
    SELECT id
           , AES_DECRYPT(first_field,'secret_salt')
           , AES_DECRYPT(second_field,'secret_salt') 
    FROM   table
    WHERE  status = 1
```

I found this query but it does not work either.

```
    SELECT  id, AES_DECRYPT(first_field,'secret_salt'), AES_DECRYPT(second_field,'secret_salt')
    FROM    table
    WHERE   first_field LIKE "%AES_ENCRYPT('user search value','secret_salt')%"
```

Comment: To debug I'd suggest hard-coding in some constants. Pull out an encrypted field and write a query like `SELECT AES_DECRYPT('kjhsjdkha','secret')`; to check if it returns what you're expecting.

Comment: i just deleted old data and inserted new data, and i started working fine, it was in development phase so i only had a few records, so there was no problem

Comment: The AES_ENCRYPT version won't work; each time the same data is encrypted, you get a different result.  The AES_DECRYPT versions at least stand a chance of working.  However, the processing is extremely expensive.  You should avoid having to search in encrypted columns as far as possible.

Comment: **"does not work" is _not_ a valid problem description/analysis.**

Answer (score 6):

Try using

```
WHERE CAST(AES_DECRYPT(first_field, 'secret_salt') AS CHAR) LIKE '%foo%'
```

Comment: This just saved me.  I didn't realize you might have to cast to char after decrypting.  Phew.